# Replacing numbers from alphanumeric strings

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with two sorts of labels. The first is of the form 'numeric_alphanumeric_alpha' and another which is 'alphanumeric_alpha'. I need to strip the numeric prefix from the first label so that it matches the second label. I know how to remove numbers from alphanumeric data (as below) but this would remove numbers that I need.

```
gsub('[0-9]+', '', x)
```

Below is an example of the two different labels I am encountered with well as the prefer

```
c('12345_F24R2_ABC', 'r87R2_DEFG')
```

Below is the desired output

```
c('F24R2_ABC', 'r87R2_DEFG')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple regex can do it. `^` refers to the start of a string, `\\d` refers to any digits, `+` indicates one or more time it appears.

```
gsub("^\\d+_", "", c('12345_F24R2_ABC', 'r87R2_DEFG'), perl = T)

[1] "F24R2_ABC"  "r87R2_DEFG"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code a litte modified:

`^[0-9]*`.....starts with number followed by numbers

`\\_` .... matches underscore

```
gsub('^[0-9]*\\_', '', x)
```

```
[1] "F24R2_ABC"  "r87R2_DEFG"
```